# Is it possible to give a User the option to clone a Dashboard but not edit the same Dashboard

Tags: permissions, profile, dashboard

Is it possible to give a User the option to clone a Dashboard but not edit the same Dashboard.
I have a dashboard for which I want users to clone but they should not be able to edit it.

Please let me know.

Comment: I would say no, since clone and create are essentially the same where clone is more of copy+create for which you need to have create access. I would happy if someone here could point to some other ways to do this.

Comment: You might be better asking this on the salesforce success community - its the kind of thing that Steve Molis knows inside out.